# derivative after changing variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have just studied a lesson about derivative of a function but I still confuse in the following case. Suppose that I have a function:
$$ f(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + 1$$ 
and I want to calculate $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ and it is
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 4x + 3$$

I try to change the variable $x$ such that $x=e^u$, and then
$$f(e^u) = 2e^{2u} + 3e^u + 1\quad\quad\quad (1)$$

and I have 
$$\frac{d}{du}f(e^u) = 4e^{2u}+3e^u = e^u(4e^u + 3)=\frac{dx}{du}\frac{df}{dx}\quad\quad\quad (2)$$

But I just want to take the derivative by $x$, not by $u$, that means
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(e^u) = 4e^u + 3 \quad\quad\quad (3)$$

So, I confuse between $(2)$ and $(3)$. Which is correct? Because the transformation is needed for a calculation in next step (using variable $u$) of my exercise. Maybe my question is stupid but I appreciate if anyone can explain clearly the difference in two ways of taking derivative by $x$ and $u$.

Comment: you forgot the $\frac {du}{dx}$ in $3)$

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're basically there. $$\frac{df}{dx}(e^u)=\frac{df/du}{dx/du}=\frac{4e^{2u}+3e^u}{e^u}= 4e^u+3,$$ but this is exactly what you get if you find $\frac{df}{dx}$ first and then let $x=e^u.$

Still, as pointed out in the previous answer, this is an abuse of notation (though in context, it's clear what you mean). It would be better to say $$\cfrac{\frac{d}{du}f(e^u)}{\frac{d}{du}e^u}$$ instead of $$\frac{df/du}{dx/du}.$$

Comment: Thanks Cameron Buie and Samuel Lijin, I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative describes how a function changes with respect to a variable. The derivative $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ studies how $f(x)$ changes with respect to $x$, whereas the derivative $\frac{d}{du}f(e^u)$ studies how $f(e^u)$ changes with respect to $u$, not how $f(e^u)$ changes with respect to $e^u$.

Your $(2)$ is correct, but $(3)$ is nonsensical because nowhere in $f(e^u)$ is there an $x$ that you are working with.